# Activiti process not being deployed with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, activiti

I am using Spring Boot and I am trying to deploy a very simple process.

I tried to place the process definition in a folder called `processes` in `src/main/resources`. Not sure that works, I also tried to manually deploy the process definition.

The process is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions
        xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL"
        xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn"
        targetNamespace="MyProcessesNamespace">

    <process id="oneTaskProcess" name="The One Task Process" isExecutable="true">
        <startEvent id="theStart" />
        <sequenceFlow id="flow1" sourceRef="theStart" targetRef="theTask" />
        <userTask id="theTask" name="my task" />
        <sequenceFlow id="flow2" sourceRef="theTask" targetRef="theEnd" />
        <endEvent id="theEnd" />
    </process>

</definitions>
```

The code I am using to manually deploy it is:

```
DeploymentBuilder db = repositoryService.createDeployment().
                name("Deployment name");

        Resource processesResource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:processes");
        File processesFolder = processesResource.getFile();
        Collection<File> files =
                FileUtils.listFiles(processesFolder, null, false);

        for (File f : files) {
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
            db.addInputStream(f.getName(), is);
        }

        db.deploy();
}
```

This way, I enter the loop over `files` and I actually see the correct xml is being processed. Then  `db.deploy()` is correctly executed and the application is deployed.

Then I try this JSON `{  "processDefinitionKey":"oneTaskProcess"  }` to this URL `http://myuser:mypassword@localhost:8080/runtime/process-instances` but the response is:

```
{
  "message": "Bad request",
  "exception": "no processes deployed with key 'oneTaskProcess'"
}
```

In the database, I see the deployment, but no process definitions exist (`act_re_procdef` table is empty).

What's wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My issue was on the process definition file name: it was `one-task-process.xml`, but it should be `one-task-process.bpmn20.xml`.